# %syscall - using text variable as a list of argument

Tags: sas

```
%macro comb(n,k);
    %do i=1 %to &n;
        %let x&i = &i;
    %end;
    %let variables = x1;
    %do i=2 %to &n;
        %let variables = %str(&variables, x&i);
    %end;
    %let ncomb=%sysfunc(comb(&n,&k));
    %do j=1 %to &ncomb;
        %syscall allcomb(j, k, variables);
        %put &x1 &x2;;
    %end;
%mend;
```

When I run `%comb(3,2);` I get:

```
WARNING: Argument 2 to function ALLCOMB referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is
         out of range.
```

`&variables` expand to `x1, x2, x3` and when I change the code to have `%syscall allcomb(j, k, x1, x2, x3);` it works fine. Is to possible to pass the last arguments to `allcomb` the way I try to do this?

Comment: How did you create `x1 x2 x3`?

Comment: Do you mean the `variables` variable? It's the second `%do` loop.

Comment: No, how do you (prior to the above code) put data in `x1`, `x2`, etc.

Comment: This all the code I use. When you run `comb(3,2)` it assigns value to `x1` etc. in the first `%do` loop (`x1=1`, `x2=2` and `x3=3`).

Answer (score 1):

So,I got this to work here:

```
%macro comb(n,k);
    %do i=1 %to &n;
        %let x&i = &i;
    %end;
    %let variables = x1;
    %do i=2 %to &n;
        %let variables = &variables, x&i;
        %put &=variables;
    %end;
    %let ncomb=%sysfunc(comb(&n,&k));
    %put &=ncomb &=k;
    %do j=1 %to 3;
        %syscall allcomb(j, k, &variables);
        %put &x1 &x2;
    %end;
%mend;

%comb(3,2);
```

This amounts to adding an extra `&` to variables.  I also removed the `%str` bit as I think that may have been confusing things - it's wholly unnecessary.